# Are there any supported work-arounds for Google Place API anti-caching rules?

Tags: web-services, google-places-api

I am developing a website that allows users to search in an area for restaurants. I use mostly my own data (location, cuisine type, etc) but I do not want to run my own ratings engine. I have been using the Google Places API to retrieve "rating" data for each result.

I did a lot of development on my app last month and got hit with a pretty hefty bill (loading results for each query, every time I save a file, for example).

I can limit my requests to the Google Places API in dev by turning off the feature, but ideally going forward, I'd like to limit my calls to the Google Places API, but understand that caching data (other than place_id & lat,long) is against the Terms of Service.

Does anyone have any ideas? I'm open to considering other services other than Google, but would prefer an answer inside the Google Place API ecosystem if possible.

Comment: how about only showing reviews when requested by the user?

Comment: @jpoehnelt that's what I'm leaning toward at this point. I think I may need to have my own ratings for the initial results page, and then if a user drills down, I can display ratings from other sources